# How to debug a GLSL shader?

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, opengl-es2, debugging

I cannot find any tutorial in Google and Youtube. I have a C++ program that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 API to render something on the screen. How can I debug my shaders? Any step-by-step guide? What is the easiest way to at least print variable values?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34392/debugging-shader-code?rq=1

Comment: @Byte56 this is not a duplicate. In your link there is not step by step tutorial.

Comment: Why would the question have a step-by-step tutorial? Remember that questions are duplicated, not the answers they contain.

Answer (score -2):

In general, you can't. The typical development environments only give you visibility on the C/C++ side.

So, I say "you can't" but that's obviously not exactly true. You can't step through the shader and print variables, but still we all develop and debug shaders. But it's a lot of intuiting indirectly what's going on, by repeated runs. Some of the things I do is:

- Have a simplified version of my app that only draws 1 or 2 things, so try/edit/retry goes faster
- Have a few fallback shaders that I *know* work, and swap them in when I'm doubting my own sanity...
- Use revision control, of course
- Always print out all the error messages from compiling with `glGetShaderInfoLog()`

In some game engine environments, you author shaders at a higher level, using flow diagrams and such, and the engine generates GLSL (or HLSL &c) on the fly, which is a whole different debug experience.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The answers to the duplicate question mention step-debugging tools for shaders.